# How to add id CAML grouping?

Tags: development, caml

I write this code, and I try to group by Ascending or Descending.

`<Query>
   <Where>
      <Neq>
         <FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' />
         <Value Type='Note'>" "</Value>
      </Neq>
   </Where>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' Ascending='False' />
   </OrderBy>
</Query>`

But it no work. How Could I manage to group elements?

Comment: Try removing the `<Query>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is correct and you use these lines of code

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery;
query.Query = "your query string"
```

You should remove `<Query>` tag from your sting

```
<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Note'>" "</Value></Neq></Where> <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>
```

Also I'm not sure about note field, did you try to test your query in [U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx)?

Comment: I made this query there and its no work on U2U Caml Query Builder

Comment: remove <Query> from your query

Comment: Okey now its worked fine :)